# Amazon EC2 Windows instance is taking around 4 minutes to generate password, how can get the password immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched Windows Server EC2 instance. When it is up, I tried to generate password with private key, but it is saying you have to wait for at least 4 minutes.

What to do if I want to get the password immediately?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Quick Start AMIs have software involved that do the following on first boot:

- Generate a random administrator password
- Encrypt the password using the nominated public key
- Provide the encrypted key in the "Console" output

AWS can then retrieve the encrypted password, decrypt it with the supplied private key, then provide it to the user to allow them to login.

The time taken to generate the random password depends on how fast the remote computer can pass it back to AWS via the Console output.

**However, you do not need to use this method to connect!**

Other other options are:

- Create your own AMI with a password already set, *or*
- [Join an EC2 Instance to Your AWS Managed Microsoft AD Directory - AWS Directory Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_join_instance.html), *or*
- Provide a User Data script that sets a specific password

In fact, it is recommended that once a random password has been set, you should replace this password with one not known by AWS or, preferably, connect to an Active Directory domain. Basically, you should follow your standard corporate security process rather than relying on the random password and keypair used when launching a new instance.

Comment: Hi John, really appreciate your help, can you please share the User Data script, how to set password. Either in powershell or any script.

Comment: I'm not a Windows person, but you could probably ask the question on ServerFault.